# How To Instantly Save Screen To File With One Key

Tags: windows-7, windows, screenshot, image-processing, autosave

Using Windows 7, I would like to set up a single key, ideally a key which is not commonly used for anything else like PrintScrn, to automatically save the screen **to a file**. File name or location is not important.

By default, the screen is saved to a clipboard, which means that if you take another screenshot, the first one is overwritten. It makes it very difficult to capture multiple screenshots quickly, or in real time.

Does anyone know if there is a way to accomplish this? I don't know if there could be an obscure configuration for this. If there needs to be a third-party application, it should be as light as possible.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: OneNote has a screenshot feature, it's not a single key, but there exists third-party programs that would accomplish that requirement.  You could also wrote your utility to do this.

Comment: [Screenshot Captor](https://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/screenshotcaptor/index.html) will also do this (and many other wonderful things). You might need to tweak the preferences a little.